# Subscribe to mass transit topic with a base path on Azure Service Bus

Tags: azureservicebus, masstransit

I'm separating out some events using the base path property. Like so:

```cs
cfg.Publish<IMyEvent>(p =>
{
    p.EnablePartitioning = false;
    p.BasePath = "qwerty";
});
```

I can see the topic created successfully in the bus explorer (`qwerty/mynamespace/imyevent`).

However I'm unable to subscribe to this topic. The logic I have been using without base path is:

```cs
cfg.SubscriptionEndpoint<IMyEvent>(host, "BlaServiceSubscription", e =>
{
    e.Consumer<MyConsumer>(provider);
});
```

How can I tell the consumer what the base path it should be using is?